# Varying intercepts and slopes with group-level predictor model - coef.est

Tags: r

I am doing a multilevel analysis where I am looking at peoples life satisfaction compared to sclmeet, health, wkdcorga and hincfeel and my group level is country and density (c_pode_2014).

I want to look at the Varying intercepts and slopes with group-level predictor model:

M4 = lmer ( stflife ~ sclmeet + health + wkdcorga + hincfel + sclmeet:c_pode_2014  + health:c_pode_2014  + wkdcorga:c_pode_2014 
            + hincfel:c_pode_2014  + (1 + sclmeet + health + wkdcorga + hincfel|cntry), data = countries)
display(M4)

> the is the result I get: 
>                       coef.est coef.se
>   (Intercept)           9.73     0.21
>   sclmeet               0.16     0.03
>   health               -0.50     0.03
>   wkdcorga              0.13     0.04
>   hincfel              -0.60     0.09
>   sclmeet:c_pode_2014   0.00     0.00
>   health:c_pode_2014    0.00     0.00
>   wkdcorga:c_pode_2014  0.00     0.00
>   hincfel:c_pode_2014   0.00     0.00

Error terms:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr
 cntry    (Intercept) 0.44
          sclmeet     0.05     -1.00
          health      0.03     -0.97  0.97
          wkdcorga    0.05     -0.32  0.32  0.55
          hincfel     0.14      0.78 -0.78 -0.92 -0.84

### Residual             1.53

> number of obs: 10278, groups: cntry, 6
>
> AIC = 38126.7, DIC = 37889.7
>
> deviance = 37983.2

Why are the coefficients.est and coefficients.se =0 ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do I do that and what does it mean to do that?

Comment: Disregard, I misread your formula.